# Render node in Neos

Tags: fluid, neoscms

I downloaded the Lelesys.Plugin.SlideShow plugin for my project. This introduces two NodeType prototypes:

```
prototype(Lelesys.Plugin.SlideShow:SlideShowContainer) < prototype(TYPO3.Neos:Content)
prototype(Lelesys.Plugin.SlideShow:SlideShowContainer) {
  templatePath = 'resource://Lelesys.Plugin.SlideShow/Private/Templates/TypoScript/SlideShowContainer.html'
  slideShowContainerCollection = ${q(node).children('slideShowContainer').children('[instanceof TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Image]')}
  slideShowContainerItemCollection = TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection
  slideShowContainerItemCollection {
    nodePath = 'slideShowContainer'
  }
  properties = ${node.properties}
}

prototype(Lelesys.Plugin.SlideShow:SlideShowItem) < prototype(TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Image)
prototype(Lelesys.Plugin.SlideShow:SlideShowItem) {
  templatePath = 'resource://Lelesys.Plugin.SlideShow/Private/Templates/TypoScript/SlideShowItem.html'
  slideShowContainerProperty = ${q(node).property('_parent.parent.properties')}
  sliderImageTitle = ${q(node).property('sliderImageTitle')}
  sliderImageDescription = ${q(node).property('sliderImageDescription')}
}
```

As you can see, it comes with predefined templates. I replaced it with my own. In the template for the SlideShowContainer, I have roughly this situation:

```
<f:if condition="{slideShowContainerCollection -> f:count()}>1">
  <f:then>
    <f:for each="{slideShowContainerCollection}" as="slideitem" iteration="slideitemIterator">
      <media:image image="{slideitem.properties.image}" alt="test" />
```

This is the best I managed to do by now, to use the TYPO3.Media ImageViewHelper to render the Image inside the SlideShowItem, which inherits from TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Image.

The normal implementation is this:

```
{slideShowContainerItemCollection -> f:format.raw()}
```

This basically takes the ContentCollection from Neos and renders it completely, using the template from the SlideShowItem, as it is supposed to.

Now, since the SlideShowItem node type is already associated with a template, I figure there must be a straight forward way to render the SlideShowItem nodes with a simple command, automatically taking into account the configured template. Something like:

```
<f:render node="{slideitem}">
```

That is just my fantasy, but there should be a way to render single nodes when it is so easy for Neos to automatically generate the output of the whole collection of nodes.

My understanding of the node system and Fluid engine is quite that of a novice. What would be the closest thing to what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but I think that you can accomplish this with the following TypoScript

```
myRenderingOfAnItem = Lelesys.Plugin.SlideShow:SlideShowItem {
  //Custom modifications for you rendering
}
```

use the ts:render viewHelper inside your f:for loop

```
<ts:render path="myRenderingOfAnItem" context="{node: slideItem}" />
```

Remember to import ts namespace in your Fluid template

```
{namespace ts=TYPO3\TypoScript\ViewHelpers}
```